# I am trying to achieve a true value on terraform with if condition, but my code does not work properly

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, terraform

I want to create a private service link and private `DNS` zone if my hostname is admin and environment is `uat` , but my if statement is always returned true. Here is a snippet of the code

```
resource "your_resource_type" "example_resource" {
  for_each = merge([
    for i in setproduct(keys(local.static_web_app_names), keys(var.environments)) : {
      join("-", i) = {
        environment = i[1]
        hostname    = local.static_web_app_names[i[0]]
        prefixes    = i
      }
    }
  ]...)


  private_endpoints_subnet_resource = (each.value["environment"] != "uat" && each.value["hostname"] != "admin") || each.value["environment"] != "prod" ? local.private_endpoints_subnet_resource : null
  private_dns_zone_resource        = (each.value["environment"] != "uat" && each.value["hostname"] != "admin") || each.value["environment"] != "prod" ? lookup(var.dns_zones_resources[each.value["environment"]][each.value["hostname"]], "private", null) : null
  private_dns_zones_ids            = (each.value["environment"] != "uat" && each.value["hostname"] != "admin") || each.value["environment"] != "prod" ? var.private_dns_zones_ids[each.value["environment"]] : []
}
```

Whenever I use a single test condition, this works as intended

```
resource "your_resource_type" "example_resource" {
  for_each = merge([
    for i in setproduct(keys(local.static_web_app_names), keys(var.environments)) : {
      join("-", i) = {
        environment = i[1]
        hostname    = local.static_web_app_names[i[0]]
        prefixes    = i
      }
    }
  ]...)

 
  private_endpoints_subnet_resource = each.value["environment"] != "uat"  ? local.private_endpoints_subnet_resource : null
  private_dns_zone_resource        = each.value["environment"] != "uat"  ? lookup(var.dns_zones_resources[each.value["environment"]][each.value["hostname"]], "private", null) : null
  private_dns_zones_ids            = each.value["environment"] != "uat"  ? var.private_dns_zones_ids[each.value["environment"]] : []

}
```

It removes all the private `DNS` and private service links from the configuration where the environment is `uat`.

Comment: What is the problem you have? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

From your statement "I want to create a private service link and private DNS zone if my hostname is admin and environment is uat". The "prod" check is not needed, and you should be checking if it is `==`  as below.

```
private_endpoints_subnet_resource = (each.value["environment"] == "uat" && each.value["hostname"] == "admin") ? local.private_endpoints_subnet_resource : null
private_dns_zone_resource         = (each.value["environment"] == "uat" && each.value["hostname"] == "admin") ? lookup(var.dns_zones_resources[each.value["environment"]][each.value["hostname"]], "private", null) : null
private_dns_zones_ids             = (each.value["environment"] == "uat" && each.value["hostname"] == "admin") ? var.private_dns_zones_ids[each.value["environment"]] : []
```

Comment: the thing is it does not work no matter what i change